# Calling java from shellscript with parameters

Tags: java, shell, unix

From a shell script, I would like to call a shell script which calls a java program. The parameters to the java program are passed from the first shell script.

shellscript1 --> shellscript2 (set par1)  --> Java par1

I have tried to source shellscript2 in shellscript1. Still couldnt pass parameters. I dont want to export the parameters and call shellscript2

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: The way mentioned in other post didn't work. Thats why I had rephrased the question exactly as per my requirements. Anyway, I had found a work around to call the java code directly. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Do not use shellscript 2 but add the param to shellscript 1. Using 2 shellscripts makes it complex.